# Extracting index value in excel matrix

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table like this

```
A   2   3   4
B   1   2   5
C   6   2   3
```

and I would like to define a function which extracts the letter corresponding to the minimum value of the 3x3 matrix of numeric values. The desired output would be "B".

I've come up with this function:

```
=INDEX(A1:A3;MATCH(MIN(B1:D3);B1:D3;0))
```

But it doesn't work. I assume that the problem is in the MATCH function, because it doesn't return a number, but I can't figure out how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATCH is designed for one column or one row.  Use Aggregate which will iterate the range and test each cell.  It is a little slower and the range needs to be only the data set.

```
=INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(B1:D3)/(B1:D3 = MIN(B1:D3)),1))
```

[image]